# Capture Audio from audio stream and scan for a frequency

Tags: c#, audio, stream, frequency

I want to create an application, which captures an audio stream from a certain url. (.mp3 and .aac) For example: http://media-sov.musicradio.com/SPTest
The application should buffer or listens to this stream and scan for a certain frequency, let's say 500 Hz.

A console application is enough. Is this somehow possible? Is there a certain library or even any sources to check?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question.  You want to download an encoded/compressed stream, decode it into raw audio, and analyze the audio signal looking for specific frequencies.  I think you'll have better luck investigating each of those parts individually.

Comment: Thank you, helped me already.